# How to parse CSV files into a dictionary and use them one by one (without using the CSV library)

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a homework assignment that essentially requires you to parse a CSV file (preferably without using the CSV library, but really whatever's easiest is fine) and move its contents into a dictionary, and from that dictionary print certain parts and use other parts as answers.

I've tried this method:

```
with open('questions.txt') as f:
  questions={}
  for line in f:
    csvvalues = line.split(',')
    csvvalues = [x.rstrip() for x in csvvalues]
    questions[csvvalues[-1]] = {
      'Q' : csvvalues[0],
      'A' : csvvalues[1:len(csvvalues)-1]
    }

  print(questions)
```

But the formatting came out very weird and unusable.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
quiz={}
f=open("questions.txt","r")
for line in f:
     parts=line.split(",")
     quiz[parts[0]]=[parts[1],parts[2],parts[3],parts[4].strip("\n")]
for i in range(10): 
     print(quiz)
     ans=input("Input your answer")
     if ans==quiz[parts[5]]:
          print("Correct!")
     else:
          print("Nope, the answer is")
f.close()
```

But it comes up with a KeyError, and both questions (see my file for context) come out at the same time, which I don't want - they should come one at a time.

Expected results:

```
Which birthstone is associated with the month of May? Diamond, Ruby, Emerald, Sapphire 
Input your answer <user inputs answer>
Correct! (or)
Nope, the right answer is (correct answer as A B C or D)
(then next question is outputted)
```

MY CSV FILE: ("questions")

```
Which birthstone is associated with the month of May?,Diamond,Ruby,Emerald,Sapphire,C
Which two colours as on the flag of Poland?,Red and Green, Blue and White, Green and White, Red and White,D
```

Comment: Clearly, `parts[5]` isn't a key in `quiz` because your code says that `parts[0]` is the key: `quiz[parts[0]]=[...]`.

Comment: @ForceBru Ohh right I see. Sorry, I'm new to Python. How would I move forward then?

Comment: Please format the csv file correctly. It is unreadable.

Comment: @Praveenkumar It's readable for me. I modified it - can you read it now?

Comment: Change parts(5) to parts(4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to use third-party libraries:

```
def parse_csv(file_name: str) -> dict:
    retval = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.strip().split(',')
            key, *values = (v.strip() for v in data)
            retval[key] = values
    return retval

questions = parse_csv('questions.txt')
for question, answers in questions.items():
    correct = answers[-1]
    answers = answers[:-1]

    result = input(f"{question}: {','.join(answers)}")

    if result == correct:
        print('Yeah, mate!')
    else:
        print(f'The correct answer is {correct!r}')
```

Comment: Holy...! Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate this! I'll do my best to understand the code.